# To get first and last occurrence when cut using a delimiter

Tags: shell, awk, sed, sh, cut

I have a text file a.txt with following data

```
 abc/def/ghi  
 jkl/mno/pqr/stu
```

I need to cut them so that I get first and last string with "/" as delimiter

Output expected is

```
abc ghi
jkl stu


cat a.txt |cut -d "/" -f1               #gives me first cell
cat a.txt |rev |cut -d "/" -f1 |rev     #gives me last cell
```

I want both cells to be available in single command. Kindly help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use awk for this,

```
$ awk -F/ '{print $1,$NF}' file
abc ghi  
jkl stu
```

Through `sed`,

```
$ sed 's~^\([^/]*\).*\/\(.*\)$~\1 \2~g' file
abc ghi  
jkl stu
```

Through `perl`,

```
$ perl -pe 's;^([^/]*).*\/(.*)$;\1 \2;g' file
abc ghi  
jkl stu
```

Ugly hack through `grep` and `paste`,

```
$ grep -oP '^[^/]*|\w+(?=$)' file | paste -d' ' - -
abc ghi
jkl stu
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `sed` ( without capture ),

```
sed 's@/.*/@ @g' yourfile
```

**Test:**

```
$ sed 's@/.*/@ @g' yourfile
abc ghi  
jkl stu
```